# how to set radio checked of an input by .val()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, input

i want to select an input by his value.
the problem is that i got a 4 radio inputs
and when the user clicks "next" it saves the value of that answer in AnsW array.
and when the user clicks "back" i want the input radio button with the value that i have in my AnsW array to be checked, so the user can know what he has selected and change his answer to something else.

html code:

```
<ul>
            <li class="li0">
                <input type="radio" value="ch1" name="choice" id="li0"/>
                <label for="li0"></label>
            </li>
            <li class="li1">
                <input type="radio" value="ch2" name="choice" id="li1"/>
                <label for="li1"></label>
            </li>
            <li class="li2">
                <input type="radio" value="ch3" name="choice" id="li2"/>
                <label for="li2"></label>
            </li>
            <li class="li3">
                <input type="radio" value="ch4" name="choice" id="li3"/>
                <label for="li3"></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

my code is:

```
function go_back(){
    $("#back").bind("click",function(){
        qNum--;
        showQuestion(qNum);
        if(AnsW.length === 0){
            calcAnswers--;
        }
        alert(AnsW[qNum]);
        tempAns = AnsW[qNum];//user last answer which is false i need this to make the radio button point to that answer
        //alert( $("input[value='tempAns']"));
        $("input").val(tempAns).attr('checked', true);
        alert(tempAns);
        //alert(tempAns);
        AnsW.splice(-1,1);//delete the false answer from the array i need this to make sure that the answer is deleted and there wont be overload of wrong answers
        //alert(deleteAns);
        if(qNum === 0){
            $("#back").css({"visibility":"hidden"})
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: do u have these questions in seperate pages? or are the questions dynamic?

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) allow you to find elements based on their attributes, an exact match example:

```
 $("element.class[attribute=value]")
```

Check the value attribute in the selector

```
$("input[value="+tempAns+"]").prop('checked', true)
```

Comment: Excellent point @hungerpain the property is boolean and changes with the current state of the element, while the attribute stays the same.